# jquery adding audio onclick

Tags: jquery, audio

Good evening , everyone. I am having some issue trying to add sound effect whenever I click on object. I want to add a sound at the same time as javascript shows the message to user. How do I do that ?

**Html code here:**

```
     <audio id="music"  preload="auto">
        <source src="sounds/backgroundMusic.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="sounds/backgroundMusic3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="sounds/sound1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
```

**Script.js* here:*

```
 if(gameData.opendCardsNumber > 0 && gameData.opendCardsNumber < 10)
                        {
                            for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                                {       
                                    var randomString = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);
                                    var randomStringElement = messages[randomString];
                                    $("#messageBox").html(randomStringElement);
                                }
                        }
```

Comment: `$('#music')[0].play()`

Comment: @Xorifelse thank you , mate :) worked just perfectly